# SQL ORACLE - Selecting author with most publications (most rows) using MAX()

Tags: sql, oracle, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have problem with Oracle SQL script. I need to select all the authors (logins) with most publications. If there are more logins with the same number of publications, I need to select them all.
[list of publications looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgiNg.png)

I **need** to use **MAX()** function.. so far I have tried doing something like this:

```
SELECT P.LOGIN, COUNT(*)
FROM PISE P
GROUP BY P.LOGIN, HAVING COUNT(*) >= MAX(PUBLICATIONS)  
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS PUBLICATIONS
FROM PISE P
GROUP BY P.LOGIN
);
```

resulting in ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

or

```
SELECT P.LOGIN, COUNT(*) as PUBLICATIONS
FROM PISE P
GROUP BY P.LOGIN HAVING PUBLICATIONS >= MAX(PUBLICATIONS);
```

resulting in ORA-00904: "PUBLICATIONS": invalid identifier

or

```
 SELECT P.LOGIN, COUNT(*)
    FROM PISE P
    WHERE COUNT(*) IN (
    SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) 
    FROM PISE
    );
```

resulting in ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here.

[This is the result I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUOR4.png)

(without Jmeno and Prijmeni column).

Comment: Why PUBLICATIONS >= MAX(PUBLICATIONS) and not = (equal)? In the other attempt, why COUNT(*) IN (SELECT MAX...) and not = (equal) instead of "IN"?  In both cases, = makes the most sense.  ALSO: The authors' first name and last name are not in the original table, how do you want them to appear in the output? You will likely need a join (if first and last names are in another table, as they should be), but you provided no information about that.

Comment: Yes, changing >= makes no difference at all. In the begining that what I had there, but while trying to somehow solve it, I tried everything that came to my mind.

changin IN to = ends with the same result.

EDIT: first name and last name is included in different table, i will add it later, but thats not what i need to be solved, so i neglected it. in other words, i tried to simplify my problem to the root of the problem.

Comment: Right - I wasn't suggesting that will fix the queries (after all, both >= and "IN" are perfectly legitimate - just inefficient). Your query fails because after the first query you immediately start a subquery. You probably meant to have a WHERE clause there, but the word WHERE is not present. The second query fails because the alias PUBLICATIONS is added (in the SELECT clause) only AFTER the GROUP BY clause, so at the GROUP BY level there is no identifier "PUBLICATIONS" (yet).

Comment: The third query fails because you can't have COUNT(*) in the WHERE clause. First the WHERE conditions are evaluated, and some rows are selected and others are rejected. COUNT() counts how many rows where selected (passed the WHERE conditions), so COUNT() itself can't be part of the WHERE clause (circular logic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "with clause" (available in versions 11 and above):

```
with a as (select login, count(*) as cnt from p group by login),
     b as (select max(cnt) as max_cnt from a)
select a.login, a.cnt from a, b where a.cnt = b.max_cnt 
/
```

Comment: ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here
04044. 00000 -  "procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here"
*Cause:    A procedure, function, or package was specified in an
           inappropriate place in a statement.
*Action:   Make sure the name is correct or remove it.

I presume my version is older :)

Comment: ??  What I provided is a SQL statement, did you try to wrap it into a procedure or function? It probably has nothing to do with the version - certainly not with that error message. I tested the query on my version of Oracle and it works fine. What is your version? Please run the following SQL statement (NOT WRAPPED in any function or procedure) and see what it tells you:  select * from v$version

Comment: By the way, I have "p" as the name of your original table (first line of code); please change that to your actual table name.

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

I didnt wrap it in procedure. I need just this select - but it should work both ways, right?

Comment: Happy to help! What was it - the table name? Good luck!

Comment: Unrelated, but: common table expressions ("`with` clause") were already available in Oracle 9i (not 11)

Comment: @sKyTzi - you may want to close the thread (mark it answered), it still shows up in the list of unanswered questions in my searches. Thanks!